# Cannot copy from a TensorFlowLite tensor (StatefulPartitionedCall:0) with shape [1, 11] to a Java object with shape [1, 11, 4]

Tags: python, android, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-lite

I used demo app in
https://github.com/android/camera-samples/tree/main/CameraXAdvanced

I want to create an app with my custom model made with a custom image set, right now with 11 image categories.
My model code is follow:

```
import tensorflow as tf
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense, Flatten, Conv2D, MaxPooling2D, Input
from keras.preprocessing.image import ImageDataGenerator

DATASET_DIR = "path/to/my/images/folders"
BATCH_SIZE = 32
IMAGE_SIZE = 300

datagen = ImageDataGenerator(validation_split=0.3, rescale=1. / 255)

train_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(DATASET_DIR,
                                              target_size=(IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE),
                                              batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                                              class_mode="categorical",
                                              subset="training"
                                              )

test_generator = datagen.flow_from_directory(DATASET_DIR,
                                             target_size=(IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE),
                                             batch_size=BATCH_SIZE,
                                             class_mode="categorical",
                                             subset="validation"
                                             )

model = Sequential()
model.add(Conv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=2, padding="same", activation="relu", input_shape=(IMAGE_SIZE, IMAGE_SIZE, 3)))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2, strides=2))
model.add(Conv2D(filters=32, kernel_size=2, padding="same", activation="relu"))
model.add(MaxPooling2D(pool_size=2, strides=2))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(32, activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(11, activation="softmax"))

model.compile(optimizer="sgd", loss="categorical_crossentropy", metrics=["accuracy"])
model.fit(train_generator, epochs=30)

model.save("H5_model/my_model.h5")
```

Then I converted my "h5 model" in "tflite model" with this code:

```
import tensorflow as tf
model = tf.keras.models.load_model('H5_model/my_model.h5')
converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_keras_model(model)
tfl_model = converter.convert()
file = open('TFLITE_model/my_model.tflite', 'wb')
file.write(tfl_model)
```

Then in Android class "CameraActivity.kt", I replaced line 346, 347

```
private const val MODEL_PATH = "coco_ssd_mobilenet_v1_1.0_quant.tflite"
private const val LABELS_PATH = "coco_ssd_mobilenet_v1_1.0_labels.txt"
```

with my model name (after inserted my file model in assets):

```
private const val MODEL_PATH = "my_model.tflite"
private const val LABELS_PATH = "my_model.txt" //file with list of my image categories
```

With this code I received the follow error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot copy to a TensorFlowLite tensor (serving_default_conv2d_input:0) with 480000 bytes from a Java Buffer with 120000
```

So in this code in "CameraActivity.kt"

```
    private val tfImageProcessor by lazy {
        val cropSize = minOf(bitmapBuffer.width, bitmapBuffer.height)
        ImageProcessor.Builder()
            .add(ResizeWithCropOrPadOp(cropSize, cropSize))
            .add(ResizeOp(
                tfInputSize.height, tfInputSize.width, ResizeOp.ResizeMethod.NEAREST_NEIGHBOR))
            .add(Rot90Op(-imageRotationDegrees / 90))
            .add(NormalizeOp(0f, 1f))
            .build()
    }
```

In ".add list" I've added this line:

```
.add(CastOp(DataType.FLOAT32))
```

because my model is in float32.
But with this code I received the follow error:

```
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot copy from a TensorFlowLite tensor (StatefulPartitionedCall:0) with shape [1, 11] to a Java object with shape [1, 11, 4]
```

After some search, 11 is the number of my elements, and 4 are the locations of the box outside the located image.
But in my trained model I don't have 4 locations, I just trained my model to recognize my image set.
But in "coco_ssd_mobilenet" model, these 4 locations exist! But how this? I don't know what to do.
Any ideas please?

Comment: Maybe the `numpy` modules `reshape()` function is what you're looking for

Comment: Hi, excuse me, I'm a newbie, could you help me how make this reshape with my model please? Where do I have to add this script? In training script or in tflite conversion script?